# Is there any way to get the Selection Tree dropdown of Navis Works in Model Browser of Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Like the picture showing, there are couple of variations(**Standard, Compact, Properties, Sets**) of selection tree in Navis works. Is it possible to get those variation in forge Model Browser? Is there any default implementation? If not, please share some ideas how I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Model Derivative service does not extract this kind of information from Navisworks models. And looking at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure, there doesn't seem to be any configuration option that would allow for the "selection tree" data to be extracted, either.

Comment: Could you please share some idea, how can I make such  type of sets from model derivative data? How Navis works actually makes those groups? I hope, that will help to implement similar kind of things in forge viewer!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Navisworks so I have no idea how those sets/groups are defined. But I will ask the team responsible for the NWD-to-SVF translation, and see what they think.

Comment: In the meantime, the only thing I can think of is building these sets during runtime, using Viewer APIs, based on certain properties of your model's elements. For example, if each object contains some kind of property describing the NWD file it came from, let's say called `Source File`, you could find the dbIDs of all objects coming from a specific file using something like this: `viewer.search("PKM_E19253.nwd", function onSuccess(ids) { viewer.select(ids); }, function onError(err) { alert(err); }, ["Source File"]);`.